# In Python - Selenium2 how to set the time for which a webdriver instance should wait,when loading a page,before giving a timeout exception?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-bindings

I tried it by instantiating a webdriver using the time out as the third parameter as shown below:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(None, None, 5)
```

and then used the driver to fetch a web page like so

```
self.driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

However it waits indefinitely for the page to load. 
Also tried out `WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3)` where self.driver is a webdriver instance, but to no avail.

OS-Windows Vista ; Python 2.7 ; Selenium2  ; Python-Selenium bindings 2.8

Any ideas?

EDIT: Seems that it doesn't exist for python and a request for the same has already been [put in](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=687&q=python&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WebDriverWait should be used like:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver : driver.title.lower().startswith("cheese!"))
```

Please refer to: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html